# JavaScript reducing memory usage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-scraping, async.js

I have a script which stores approx 10 simple variables using "let" within an async.js loop (Meaning the data doesn't grow in size really) as well as logs to the console for each loop. Within a minute of looping once per 1-3 seconds (depending on page loading speed) almost 1 GB of RAM is used... And the amount grows consistently to crashing point. I've tried clearing the console to reduce the ram usage but it doesn't drop it at all so now I'm not really sure what could possibly be the issue.

```js
$('body').prepend('<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/async/2.6.0/async.min.js"></script>');

const scrapeTimer = setInterval(() => {
  if(typeof async === 'object') {
    console.log('Async.min.js loaded... Starting scraping');
    scrape();
    clearInterval(scrapeTimer);
  }
}, 250);

const scrape = function() {
  let x = 0;
  let lastIndex = 0;
  let uploadCount = 0;
  let start = new Date();

  async.whilst(() => {
    if(x === 100) {
      x = 0;
      console.log('Reached 100 listings, resetting x');
    }

    return $('.colnum')[x] !== undefined;
  }, next => {
    let index = Number($('.colnum')[x].innerText);
    let element;
    let offset = false;

    if(index !== lastIndex + 1) {
      console.log(`Offset index! Expected index: ${ lastIndex + 1 } got: ${ index } on x: ${ x }`);

      element = $('.colnum').filter(function(pos) {
        if($(this).text() !== (lastIndex + 1).toString())
          return false;

        x = pos;
        index = lastIndex + 1;
        offset = true;
        console.log(`Fixed offset index: ${ index } x: ${ x }`);
        return true;
      }).parents().filter('.listing');

      if(element.length === 0) {
        console.log('Failed to fix offset');
        debugger;
      }
    } else {
      element = $($('.colnum')[x]).parents().filter('.listing');

      if(element.length === 0) {
        console.log('Index corect but no listing element');
        debugger;
      }
    }

    const mlsId = element.find('.columnlink').first().text();
    let listing = {
      mlsId,
      status: (element.find('.status_A').length !== 0) ? 'active':'inactive',
      price: Number(element.find('.price').first().text().replace(/[^0-9\.-]+/g, '')),
      address: element.find('.street-address').first().text(),
      locality: element.find('[ls="csz"]').first().text(),
      dwellingType: $(element.find('td')[8]).text(),
      bedrooms: (/\S/.test($(element.find('td')[9]).text())) ? Number($(element.find('td')[9]).text()):null,
      bathrooms: (/\S/.test($(element.find('td')[10]).text())) ? Number($(element.find('td')[10]).text()):null,
      area: (/\S/.test($(element.find('td')[11]).text())) ? Number($(element.find('td')[11]).text().replace(/[^0-9\.-]+/g, '')):null,
      general: '',
      photos: []
    };

    $('#iframe_detail').one('load', () => {
      $('#tab_tour').click();

      const photoTimer = setInterval(() => {
        const images = $('#iframe_tour').contents().find('img');

        for(let y = 0; y < images.length; y++) {
          if(!images[y].id)
            listing.photos.push(images[y].src);

          if(images[y].src === 'http://www.flexmls.com/images/nophotoavailable-huge.png') {
            x++;
            lastIndex = index;
            return next();
          }
        }

        if(listing.photos.length !== 0) {
          $('#iframe_detail').one('load', () => {
            const generals = $('#iframe_detail').contents().find('td[style="border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: left; letter-spacing: 0pt; vertical-align: top; word-spacing: 0pt;"]');
            for(let y = 0; y < generals.length; y++)
              listing.general += generals[y].innerHTML.replace(/<\/?span[^>]*>/g, '').split('<div></div>').join('\u000A') + '\u000A';

            const publics = $('#iframe_detail').contents().find('td[style="border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);"]');
            for(let y = 0; y < publics.length; y++)
              if(publics[y].innerText.includes('Public Remarks:'))
                listing.publicRemarks = publics[y].innerText.replace('Public Remarks:', '');

            $($('#iframe_detail').contents().find('table[style="border: 1px solid #969696; width: 100%;"]')[0]).find('span[style="font-size: 8pt;"]').splice(4,8).map((detail, index) => {
              switch(index) {
                case 0:
                  listing.features = detail.innerText;
                  break;
                case 1:
                  listing.roomDetails = detail.innerText;
                  break;
                case 2:
                  listing.facts = detail.innerText;
                case 3:
                  listing.facts += '\u000A' + detail.innerText;
              }
            });

            if(index % 25 === 0) {
              $('#gridC').scrollTop($('#gridC').prop('scrollHeight'));
              console.log('Scrolling to load more listings...');
            }

            let seconds = (new Date() - start) / 1000;
            x++;
            lastIndex = index;
            uploadCount++;
            console.log('Uploaded listing: ' + listing.mlsId + ' LPS: ' + (seconds / uploadCount) + ' Total: ' + uploadCount);
            console.log({ type: 'listing', listing });
            next();
          });

          $('#tab_detail').click();
          clearInterval(photoTimer);
        }
      }, 250);
    });

    element.find('.columnlink')[0].click();
  }, err => {
    if(err)
      throw err;

    console.log({ type: 'done' });
  });
};
```

Comment: scrape runs infinitely, am I correct?

Comment: @JaromandaX Until all listings on the target is scraped, which in this case is 3000

Comment: yeah, I don't see an exit strategy .. but the code is quite convoluted, updating `x` in asynchronous callbacks of asynchronous callbacks - it's quite an effort to understand what's going on - does the console logging ever stop? if not, then you have an issue

Comment: so, within a minute, you've processed at most 60 of the 3000 listings, and already used 1GB RAM - perhaps it's all those images

Comment: @JaromandaX Turns out its their site.. I tried it manually and it was doing the same issue

Comment: that sounds wrong to be honest

Comment: @JaromandaX I literally spent 10 minutes just manually doing what I was doing (Clicking each property one by one, and their photos / details views) and the ram was going up at a constant rate. Once I got to 60-100 listings the ram was at 1+ GB usage (and staying there). I closed the tab and it went directly down. Positive it's the site I'm scraping. I'm just gonna limit the amount of searches I do for each list and close the page / start

Comment: Yeah. I meant about your reason on your answer. They don't clear their caches wouldn't effect your memory

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the issue was the 3rd party site I was scraping.. It seems they don't clean their caches or something and the ram is going up constantly at a steady rate